# method to aggregate by appending to the vector in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame, let's say it is like the following

```
1 2
1 3
2 4
3 2
2 1
1 7
```

I want to aggregate it into the following form:

```
1 2,3,7
2 4,7
3 2
```

How I can do that in R? Thank you for the help.

Comment: What structure do you want your result to be?  a data.frame? what about the structure of the second column?  `with(yourdata, split(column_1, column_2))` will do this... sorta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `aggregate` as in:

```
dat <- read.table(text="1 2
1 3
2 4
3 2
2 1
1 7")

aggregate(V2 ~ V1, dat, paste, collapse = ", ")

## > aggregate(V2 ~ V1, dat, paste, collapse = ", ")
##   V1      V2
## 1  1 2, 3, 7
## 2  2    4, 1
## 3  3       2
```

Or (per Justin's question) use `c` instead as in:

```
aggregate(V2 ~ V1, dat, c)
```

Comment: Or just split: `split(dat$V2, dat$V1)`

Comment: +1. Sorry for the last minute requirement. If I want to get V2 as a vector rather than a string, how to do that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Qiang Li My second approach does this or hadley's approach (his keeps it as a list rather than putting it together as a `data.frame`; this approach is more sensible)

Comment: But what I am getting is: > length(aggregate(V2 ~ V1, dat, c)[2][1,1])
[1] 1
> aggregate(V2 ~ V1, dat, c)[2][1,1]
$`0`
[1] 2 3 7

Comment: Then your data isn't like you posted.  I suggest you post the actual data if you can or at the very least use `str(dat)` so we can see the structure of your data.  Or you've overwritten `c` with something else.

Comment: @TylerRinker, `aggregate(V2 ~ V1, dat, c)` will work as expected only if the number of rows in each group is different. If they are all equal, then `aggregate` will create several rows instead of collapsing the results in a single row.

Comment: Well `split` ought to do the trick then.  ANd if you really need a dataframe: `dat2 <- data.frame(V1 = sort(unique(dat$V1))); dat2$V2 <- split(dat$V2, dat$V1)`